# Generic object with private constructor

Tags: java, generics, private-constructor

Here is my problem. I would like to have a class with a private constructor that can be created with more than one static method, exactly like `Box.createHorizontalBox()`. Where it gets complicated is when this class uses generics.

Please, tell me how to do this properly:

```
private WorkFlow(int _arrowSize) {
  this.arrowSize = _arrowSize;
  this.elements = new ArrayList<T>();
}

public static WorkFlow<T> createHorizontalWorkFlow<T>(int _arrowSize) {
  WorkFlow<T> workFlow = new WorkFlow<T>(_arrowSize);
  workFlow.vertical = false;
  return workFlow;
}
```

This is not working: Eclipse underlines the `int` from `createHorizontalWorkFlow<T>(int _arrowSize)` and gives me the error `Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)`

Comment: Why don't you return anything from your static method?

Comment: @BoltClock Oops, edited! I forgot to copy a line...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static <T> WorkFlow<T> createHorizontalWorkFlow(int _arrowSize) {
  WorkFlow<T> workFlow = new WorkFlow<T>(_arrowSize);
  workFlow.vertical = false;
  return workFlow;
}
```

You were pretty close.  Just had the `<T>` in the wrong place - you must declare the generic type *before* the return type.

Comment: Wow, I was almost there ;-) thanks a lot. As fr the `this`, it was a tpyo. I corrected it.

Comment: static "this" admonishment removed :). Also, please "Accept" my answer if you feel it is correct - that way the question is shown as "answered" and ppl don't keep adding more attempts etc - oh you've done it. thx :)

Comment: I was about to, but you answered too quickly, I had to wait 15 minutes ;-)